# Ionic 3 - POST Data to Heroku Endpoint

Tags: node.js, heroku, ionic-framework, ionic3

so I have a back-end service running on Heroku at the endpoint `https://sample.herokuapp.com/`. I am trying to POST the following JSON object to the `/bug/` endpoint:

```
{
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "name": "Anthony",
    "text": "Test Bug",
    "picture": "Empty"
}
```

If I POST this data in *Insomnia* or *Postman*, it works perfectly and returns an HTML response with the parsed information. However, **when I POST this data using the following code in Ionic 3,**

```
sendMail(type:string, text:string):void {
            this.nativeStorage.getItem('sample').then((sample) => {
                  var data = new Object();
                  data["name"] = sample.name
                  data["email"] = sample.email;
                  data["picture"] = sample.picture;
                  data["text"] = text;

                  this.db.object('/general/sample').take(1).subscribe((sample) => {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        var endpoint = sample.address + sample.endpoints[type];

                        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                        if (this.readyState === 4) {
                            console.log("Got response: " + this.responseText);
                        }
                    });

                        xhr.open("POST", endpoint);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        console.log("sample sending: " + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
                        console.log("sample endpoint: " + endpoint);

                    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                  })
            })
    }
```

**I received the following error log in Heroku:**

```
2017-07-05T17:02:24.707431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/bug" host=sample.herokuapp.com request_id=5e679c8e-cac7-4ff2-9277-dec80a250c11 fwd="150.108.242.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=215 protocol=https
```

I have done much research on this issue, and I believe this is a CORS issue. However, I have tried using the `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers to solve this issue, but have been receiving the same errors.

I have installed the `Cordova whitelist` plugin and included the `meta` tag to my `index.html`.

This is a pretty complicated issue, so I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Just wondering why not use angular's Http object?  I have code talking to heroku as well and I have no problems.  I setup my controllers to get injected with Http object and use that in my methods to make rest calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried HttpModule and I still received the same issue in Heroku. Any ideas as to why this may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the heroku side do you have cors configured?

```
 var app = express();
 /* cors conig */
 var corOptions = {
     "origin": "*",
     "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
     "preflightContinue": true,
     allowedHeaders:  'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With'
 }
 app.use(cors(corOptions));
```

my cors dependency: "cors": "^2.8.1"

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks so much!